# Access VBA To Create Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to use Access to control Excel and take Excel data to create a pivot table.  I have this code

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("R:\Excel\TemplateReport.xlsx", False, False)

wb.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "Store!A1:I321", 6).CreatePivotTable("Test!A3", "PivotTable2", True, 6)
```

but when i run my code, I get this error

> Compile Error
>   Syntax Error

What do I need to change to have the pivot table created?

Comment: Do you you have the Excel object library loaded as a reference in Access?

Comment: Yes, the reference has been added

Comment: See my edit - i just added it

Comment: Review https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-pivot-table/ modify for Access VBA manipulating Excel objects.

Comment: I must have really messed up then.  I used the macro recorder in Excel to record my syntax and it seems very diff from the tut you posted.

Comment: the macro recorder is great to get started in a concept, but when it comes to writing fully functional and flexible code, especially when used as a reference in another application, there are a lot of things that need to be changed.

Comment: oh okay, that makes more sense.

Comment: I also used macro recorder to generate code for this process and syntax is different from what you posted. Obviously you already did some modifying.

Answer (score 1):

Remove parentheses after CreatePivotTable and change reference format for cell range.

Change to:

```
wb.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "Store!R1C1:R321C9", 6).CreatePivotTable "Test!R3C1", "PivotTable2", True, 6
```